# In AMP code, is possible to change SELECT value with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

The following simple code is checked valid by AMP Test:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="amp-script-src" content="sha384-nmWK8LCbqzr8UHBoek1oZxp4egaQXAmcy4oFoNAFQimJknkegs05tvZKZG7kCQR6">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-script" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-script-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.translator.eu/amp/s05.html" />
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
</head>  
  <body>
  <amp-script script="scriptik">
  <button id="knoflik">Click!</button>
  <select id="belzebub">
    <option value="1">11</option>  
    <option value="2">22</option>  
    <option value="3">33</option>  
    <option value="4">44</option>  
    <option value="5">55</option>  
    <option value="6">66</option>  
    <option value="7">77</option>  
    <option value="8">88</option>  
  </select>
</amp-script>
<script id="scriptik" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
  const btn = document.querySelector('#knoflik');
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var se=document.getElementById("belzebub");
    if (se) se.selectedIndex=4;
  });
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

After clicking the button, the SELECT value is successfully changed, but the last option (in this case "88") is displayed. The same result is obtained using "se.value=" etc.

**Added after three years:**
The problem remains unsolved. I can introduce another AMP valid code. While the p tag's text is changing correctly, the select behavior is strange:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="amp-script-src" content="sha384-Nk55lRKlwQStym8kR3AxlhyZjufv2FnYdR6lSKms0T1UQIKCNeguXrBVXMnt2kND">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.translator.eu/amp/s05.html" />
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
</head>  
  <body>
  <amp-state id="myDefinedState">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "promenna": "2",
      "promenny": "3"
    }
  </script>
</amp-state>
  <button on="tap:AMP.setState({myDefinedState:{promenna:myDefinedState.promenny,promenny:myDefinedState.promenna}})" >Click!</button>
  <select on="change:AMP.setState({myDefinedState:{promenna: event.value,promenny:myDefinedState.promenny}})">
    <option [selected]=" myDefinedState.promenna == '1' " value="1">1</option>  
    <option [selected]=" myDefinedState.promenna == '2' " value="2">2</option>  
    <option [selected]=" myDefinedState.promenna == '3' " value="3">3</option>  
    <option [selected]=" myDefinedState.promenna == '4' " value="4">4</option>  
  </select>
  <select on="change:AMP.setState({myDefinedState:{promenna:myDefinedState.promenna,promenny: event.value}})">
    <option [selected]=" myDefinedState.promenny == '1' " value="1">1</option>  
    <option [selected]=" myDefinedState.promenny == '2' " value="2">2</option>  
    <option [selected]=" myDefinedState.promenny == '3' " value="3">3</option>  
    <option [selected]=" myDefinedState.promenny == '4' " value="4">4</option>  
  </select>
    <p [text]="myDefinedState.promenna"></p>
    <p [text]="myDefinedState.promenny"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can try selecting the option by looping over them and selecting the desired one by attaching the `selected` attribute to the option tag; https://ampb.in/#j6QSV8km6ZmrZsaVkVhK

Comment: Thank you, but I tried it. The result was the same.